# How to calculate page size of virtual memory

Tags: operating-systems, virtual-memory

im new at OS and I want to know how to calculate the page size of this virtual memory system?

Information:

- Physical Memory - 32 KB
- Virtual Address - 16 bit
- Offset          - 12 bits

Current content of the page table is this:

[image]

I just want a formula for this and not the answer. Thank you

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? If you understand how virtual memory works, you won't need to memorize a formula because you'll be able to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @DavidRicherby actually i didnt get stuck or something. I just need the calculation for it like 2 to the power of 32 something like that. I really got no idea. And im not memorising it, i want to learn how to calculate it

Answer (score 1):

@DavidRicherby is correct You don't need a formula. You need to understand how paging works and what it means to have a 16-bit logical address with a 12-bit offset.

Logical addresses are broken into two parts — the most significant bits make up the page number, and the least significant bits make up the offset. The page number tells you what logical page the address points to. The offset indicates where the data you want is, on that page.

So, if you have aN 8-bit offset, how many different bytes on a page can you reference? $2^{8}$